# angularjs $http.get json file not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I`m new in angular, and I just get into an issue.

I wana use the ng-repeat directive to populate a page with content from an .json file.

### data.json

```
{
"projects":[
    {
        "projectName":"Project.1",
        "projectStyle":"big",
        "thumb":"",
    },{
        "projectName":"Project.2",
        "projectStyle":"big",
        "thumb":"",
    },{
        "projectName":"Project.3",
        "projectStyle":"big",
        "thumb":"",
    }
  ]
}
```

- the portfolioApp module is configured correctly, actually is auto-generated by **angular - yeoman generator**, so to be clear that I`m using nodeJS ( Yeoman | Bower | Grunt ).

### portfolio.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('portfolioApp')
.controller('PortfolioCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.portfolio = [];

    $http.get('data.json')
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.portfolio = data ;
    });
});
```

- if I manually populate the $scope.portfolio array, and comment out the $http.get, it`s working just fine, the problem is that I cannot get the data using the $http.get

### the HTML

```
....

<div ng-controller='PortfolioCtrl'>
    <div ng-repeat='project in portfolio.projects'>
        {{project.projectName}}
    </div>
</div>

....
```

What Is wrong, where am I mistaken ?

Comment: Calling `$http.get('data.json')` assumes that the data file is at the same level as the page making the request - is this the case?

Comment: I know that :) The data.json file is in the root folder | near the index.html file. ( no 404 error in console ) @kaveman

Comment: So are you getting a 200? Have you tried putting a break point inside the success function? Inspected the resulting object? Most importantly, is that json file a direct copy? Because it's not valid...

Comment: I just found / solved the problem :), Is in my .json file, after the thmub element I have a comma. Being the last element, that comma  has nothing to do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### data.json - correction

no comma after last element in each array.

```
{
"projects":[
    {
        "projectName":"Project.1",
        "projectStyle":"big",
        "thumb":""
    },{
        "projectName":"Project.2",
        "projectStyle":"big",
        "thumb":""
    },{
        "projectName":"Project.3",
        "projectStyle":"big",
        "thumb":""
    }
  ]
}
```